# Using streams().reduce to build a string from ArrayList<Integer>?

Tags: javascript, java, java-stream, reduce, binary-operators

In **JavaScript** we can build a string with other types using reducer (e.g. num to string):

```
const string = [1,2,3,4,5].reduce((acc,e) => acc += e, "") //"12345"
```

In **Java**, this pattern is not as easy when building a string from other types:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrayListOfIntegers = (ArrayList<Integer>) Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
String string = arrayListOfIntegers.stream().reduce("", (String acc, Integer e) -> acc += e); // acc += e throws error
```

The error is:

> "Bad return type: String cannot be converted to integer"

Is this pattern not possible in Java?

Comment: Java is a strongly typed language where you can't just mash an integer into a string and expect the compiler to know whether you mean concatenation or addition. Also, if you read the JavaDoc for `Stream.reduce` you'll see that all parameters involved must be of same type. So you need to map the Integer to a String before you can reduce it into a string.

Comment: Using `+=` is an obfuscation. Your actual intention is `(acc, e) -> acc + e` but your choice to use `+=` instead will lead to a pointless modification of the `acc` parameter variable which will never be read again. Besides that, in Java you would need `reduce("", (acc,e) -> acc + e, (s1,s2) -> s1 + s2)`. This works, but is horribly inefficient for streams with lots of elements. Use `map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining())` when you prefer simplicity, or `collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append) .toString()` for highest efficiency.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Java, you can simply collect the Stream using `Collectors.joining`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> arrayListOfIntegers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
        String str = arrayListOfIntegers.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining());
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1234
```

Answer (score 2):

Your are trying to reduce a list of Integers to a `String`. First map those Integers to Strings and then `reduce`:

```java
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
String value = list.stream()
                   .map(String::valueOf)
                   .reduce("", String::concat);
```

Instead of `(acc,e) -> acc+e` you could use `String::concat`. Also, the type is not compulsory in the lambda expression.

Comment: There is `.collect(Collectors.joining());` instead of the reduce. The concat version will have O(n^2) complexity I think, because it will create a new string for every element (which is O(n) in itself).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the best way is using Collectors.joining provided by @Thomas and @Arvind Kumar Avinash. But as a alternative solution I can suggest to use collect method and StringBuilder class, it doesn't generate new String object every time as in reduce case:

```java
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
String value = 
       list.stream()
           .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)
           .toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggested this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> arrayListOfIntegers = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
    String string = arrayListOfIntegers.stream().reduce("",(sum,elm)-> sum += elm.toString(),(sum1,sum2) -> sum1+sum2);
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Among few other options, here is my contribution, when you have list of int i.e primitive values please use `[IntStream][1]` here is how i have tried to do it. `rangeClosed` is inclusive of the last number. `mapToObj` is a intermediate and `collect` is a terminal operation.

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class SampleIntStream {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getComposedString(1, 5));
    }

    public static String getComposedString(int from, int to) {
        return IntStream
                .rangeClosed(from, to)
                .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
}
```